# Python3 Replacement for mimetools.choose_boundary()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking at converting a package over to working with Python3 and there's one piece that I'm missing.  According to the Python2 docs [mimetools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mimetools.html) has been replaced by [email](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.html) in Python3.

However reviewing the [differences section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.html#differences-from-mimelib) of the Python3 docs on email doesn't show a replacement of the chooseboundary() function.  Nor did my Google, SO searches, reading through the docs on the email package turn up anything.

Admittedly the function just returns a string with hostipaddr.uid.pid.timestamp.random, which I can generate myself.  Mainly asking out of curiousity.

Comment: Are you sure that it is `timestamp.random`? On my machine it seems more like `timestamp.counter`... anyway that function is quite fishy. It didn't guarantee anything, only a "high likelihood", so it may have been dropped. Still they forgot to document the change.

Comment: @Bakuriu - Yeah looks like you're right after looking at the actual function itself and not just the docs.  The docs say its `hostipaddr.uid.pid.timestamp.random` but it is a counter that's defined earlier in mimetools.

Comment: So how to rewrite that in python3?

Comment: The answer can be found in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27099290/where-is-mimetools-choose-boundary-function-in-python3).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is mimetools.choose\_boundary function in Python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27099290/where-is-mimetools-choose-boundary-function-in-python3)