# Where is mimetools.choose_boundary function in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, httprequest, mime, multipartform-data

I currently want to use the following piece of code in Python3, but found the function `mimetools.choose_boundary` to be deprecated, how to change the code and make it works?

```
import re
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
import os 
import mimetypes 
import mimetools 

def get_content_type(filepath): 
    return mimetypes.guess_type(filepath)[0] or 'application/octet-stream' 

def encode_multipart_formdata(fields, files=[]): 
    """
    fields is a sequence of (name, value) elements for regular form fields.
    files is a sequence of (name, filepath) elements for data to be uploaded as files
    Return (content_type, body) ready for httplib.HTTP instance
    """ 
    BOUNDARY = mimetools.choose_boundary() 
    CRLF = '\r\n' 
    L = [] 
    for (key, value) in fields: 
        L.append('--' + BOUNDARY) 
        L.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"' % key) 
        L.append('') 
        L.append(value) 
    for (key, filepath) in files: 
        L.append('--' + BOUNDARY) 
        L.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"; filename="%s"' % (key, os.path.basename(filepath))) 
        L.append('Content-Type: %s' % get_content_type(filepath)) 
        L.append('') 
        L.append(open(filepath, 'rb').read()) 
    L.append('--' + BOUNDARY + '--') 
    L.append('') 
    body = CRLF.join(L) 
    content_type = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=%s' % BOUNDARY 
    return content_type, body
```

Comment: It seems that function has been dropped without a direct replacement. Personally, I would just include a copy of the `email.generator` module's [`_make_boundary()`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/41ea764e8321/Lib/email/generator.py#l359) function in your code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, I answer my question since no other available answer here.

Yes, I got the result finally, for more info about my work around the question, the below information may help.

---

#### 1. What does `boundary` do in an `multipart/form-data` request?

In fact, to separate the different parts of data is such a request, we use a separator, here we call `boundary`, to divide the form data.

These parts may be field value *(plain text)*, or uploading file contents.

#### 2. First we put the boundary string in the request header.

To claim a request to be accepted as a `mulitipart/form-data` format, we first choose a special string, called `boundary`, and put it in the request header:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=FORM-BOUNDARY
```

Seeing that we choose the boundary string to be `FORM-BOUNDARY` here, in fact we can choose any string we want.

Most time we may choose a long, randomly string, to prevent collision.

#### 3. Use the chosen boundary in the request body.

In the request body *(payload)*, we separate the data with the `boundary` separator, for example:

```
--FORM-BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="template"; filename=".xls"
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel

A654ADE5^%^#%@%$@ (BINARY DATA IN THIS SECTION)
--FORM-BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="username"

admin
--FORM-BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

admin_password
--FORM-BOUNDARY--
```

Seeing that, we start one form-part with a separator, with the `boundary` after a single `--` symbol.

Then in that form-part, we export the header to claim the content type and the name of that posted field.

Then a single blank line is required.

Then we export the value(data) of that form-part.

After all form-parts, we ended the request body with a separator, with the `boundary` between two `--` symbol.

#### 4. So what does `mimetools.choose_boundary` do then?

In fact, this function (deprecated since py3) generate a random boundary, with a specified format, see: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/mimetools.html?highlight=choose_boundary#mimetools.choose_boundary

The format is:

```
'hostipaddr.uid.pid.timestamp.random'
```

Just that simple.

If we insist on getting the same result,

1. we can write the functional by ourselves.
2. Or call the `email.generator` module's `_make_boundary()` function.

> But in fact, to make it work, no need to do that, just generate a random string to replace it!